# Print command result side by side?

Tags: command-line, command

It is possible to print the result of 2 commands side by side...

Something like this

```
something `ls -l /a` `cat bla.txt`
```

result:

```
total 24                                                #while [ 1 = 1 ]; do
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy  194 Aug 13 08:50 c.in         #       echo "bla"
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy   52 Sep 24 11:48 bla.sh       #done
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy   38 Sep 24 11:48 bla1.sh      echo "bla"
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy  147 Sep 24 11:54 ble.sh
```

I know that pr can do something like this with files, but I didn't find a way to do this for commands...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

```
pr -m <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

though in your case, since you have one command and one file:

```
ls -l | pr -m - bla.txt
```

Comment: Alternatively, `paste <(cmd1) <(cmd2)` - `paste` has some additional options that `pr` doesn't, and vice versa...